# Initial portion of some tag wiki excerpts is getting cut off

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-wikis

I've noticed that on a handful of tag wikis, the initial portions are missing, even though they are reflected on the tag wiki page itself.

In the tags list:

[image]

On the tag wiki page:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is by design, the tag wiki excerpt code tries to avoid repetition in the beginning of the excerpt. See [this answer by Jeff Atwood for some more details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82702/151385). The regex is supposed to be the following, though I don't know if this is still current:

```
^.{0,40}?
(
(this\stag\s(is)?\s?)  # this tag .. this tag is|about ...
|
(used\sto\s)           # this tag is used to ...
|
(the\s[^\s]+\stag\s)   # the {foo} tag ...
|
(the\stag\s[^\s]+)     # the tag {foo} ...
|
(\s(is|are)\s)         # blah blah blah is|are ...
)
```

This causes a significant amount of collateral damage, as you have noticed.

Comment: Interesting.  It's funny, I've never noticed it before today (and I've edited a "few" in my day, hehe).  Maybe there's a new build out which enforces it more strongly now.

Comment: I wonder why it grabbed "processes" and not "study" in the other tag, though?

Comment: The last regex removes anything before an "is" or "are" in the first 40 characters, that is the one which caused your truncated examples.

Comment: Ah, I misread it. Okay.